# How to get CSS subclass with [att~="val"] selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I'm having some difficulties with getting the value of a subclass in a element. Generally, I'd verify with `.hasClass` or `.attr("class")` and then compare it, but I'm trying to get the value of a dynamically generated subclass.

Let's say that I have a `class="edit step1"`. I have to get only the step1 part but it must not depend on the number at the end, since it can be anything. I tried with `.hasClass("~step")` and some other functions but no dice.

Has anyone ever encountered a situation where this would be needed and has a solution but even any tip as to where I should look would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: show some HTML, it sounds to me like you're misusing classes.

Comment: might be cleaner/easier to add another class called 'step' without the number on all the elements

Comment: Sorry about that.

`<div class="edit step1">
</div>
<div class="edit step2">
</div>`

All I have to get is the "step" part.

Comment: @Chimoo That is unfortunately not possible since the classes are generated in another file and have to have this structure because of some later integration.

Comment: Just thought I should clear something up: `~` by itself is the general sibling combinator, introduced in CSS3. jQuery does *not* implement this combinator, however, so using it in a jQuery selector like `$('h3 ~ p')` won't work in IE6 which doesn't support it. You may want to edit your question to make it clear what exactly you're trying to select as it may confuse some people.

Comment: @BoltClock The question here was about the "Attribute Contains Word Selector [name~="value"]" from jQuery. Do you have any suggestion as to what the title should be?

Comment: I've edited the title for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a great use for classes, particular since they're already stored in an unstructured way within the element attributes.  this would be a great use for "data-step" tags.

If you can count on the names being structured, your best bet might be to split the class list and look at each element.

```
$('div[class~=" step"]').each(function(){
    steps = this.attr('class').match(/\bstep\d+/);
})
```

If you're stuck with this sub-optimal situation, the above might work

Comment: Are you by any chance referring to `<div data-step="1">`?

If that's the case - thank you for this awesome thing! :D I will most certainly force this but first I have to find some documentation regarding this tag.

Comment: @peter:  Yeah, then it becomes relatively trivial to hunt down your step.  It's html5 only, but I've never seen a browser complain about their use in non-html5 documents.  [more here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Comment: Great!
Thanks for the code (I'll use it for now) and the data-step tags idea which i'll have to force. :D

Answer (score 1):

`.attr("class")` will give you back "edit step1".

Treat it as a string. You can use `.split(" ")` to turn it into an array, then you can loop through the values and evaluate what's inside.

Comment: Correct answer but I had to choose menacigly's one, because this one gives me one additional step and he also gave me the "data-step" tags idea. Voted as useful anyway since it's correct and it's just another way to solve my problem. Thank you!